# override property value ${abc.xyz} in bean property in spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-3

I have beans xml file, which loads multiple property files for creating its beans. All these property files are under a root folder like root/abc/abc.properties , root/xyz/some.properties etc..

```
<bean id="x".....
....
<util:properties id="properties" location="${config.base.dir}/abc/abc.properties" />
......
</bean>


<bean id="y".....
....
<util:properties id="properties" location="${config.base.dir}/xyz/some.properties" />
......
</bean>
```

I want to override put the value of config.base.dir somewhere in top so that I can keep changing the root location, should this be possible by defining some property on top?

Comment: you could just put a abc.properties in the /test/resources/abc folder. is this for test time or at deploy time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Maven, you can have a version of abc.properties in the test/resources/abc/ folder. this will be picked up on the classpath before the main/resources/abc/abc.properties file.

Does this help?

Why do you want to ' keep changing the root location' ?

---

system properties overrides...

```
<!-- Configuration property files -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. but that wont actually solve my problem. there are several dependency jars in the projects. in turn those dependencies also use the property files. And they also use properties from these root for their relevant. if I want to test a certain module i need to go and change those each and every path.

Comment: You could look at using system properties as overrides, then change them before each test runs.